# What's the difference between jQuery .width(), style.width, and jQuery .css('width')?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between the values returned by `.width()` from jQuery, `.css('width')` from jQuery, and the `.style.width` attribute on a node?

I'm curious because, in trying to set the width of two table cells to be equal, the first two gave me the same wrong answer. What are they actually measuring, and why is it not the same as the value that I can see in the `.style` attribute when I view the element in a browser?

Comment: Yeah that above needs to be deleted but it won't let me for some strange reason

Comment: Check this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EjPBy/

Comment: [Just modified @A.Wolff's code to show the widths](http://jsfiddle.net/EjPBy/1/), but for `sytle.width`, there's still notthing showed..

Answer (score 8):

From [`width`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) official documentation

> The difference between .css(width) and .width() is that the latter returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, 400) while the former returns a value with units intact (for example, 400px). The .width() method is recommended when an element's width needs to be used in a mathematical calculation.

<strike>I'd say there is no difference between `.css('width')` and `.style.with` as `css()` method is used to set style object properties.</strike>

The difference between `.css('width')` / `.width()` and `.style.with` is that jQuery methods get the computed style using `window.getComputedStyle( elem, null )`. This method is used to read the actual property after CSS and styles are applied.

Comment: I'm using them to get object properties, and there's a difference of one pixel in the values they are returning. `.style.width` is correct, the others are under by 1px.

Comment: @ckersch what are CSS rules applied to this element? Just see you are talking about table cell, some kind of special styling is applied to this kind of element, maybe this could explain it. Check on other browser if you have same behaviour.

Comment: from style sheet:

background-color: #FFF;
border: 1px solid #AAA;
padding: 4px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-left: 18px;
vertical-align: top;
display: table-cell;

----------


Set with jQuery:
width: 124px;

Comment: @ckersch: udpdated my answer, does that explain the difference you see?

Comment: Nope. `window.getComputedStyle( elem, null ).width` gives the same result as `style.width`, which is different from what jQuery is giving me.

Comment: @ckersch: maybe you can create a jsfiddler and add a non minimized jquery version to debug. I could help you if you create the jsfiddler for us.

Answer (score 2):

Complementing Claudio Redi's answer: see the difference live: http://jsfiddle.net/vovkss/kPXaB/

I've used `cm` units *intentionally* to demonstrate that **the output of `.css('width')` *may* be converted to pixels** (or other units), while `.width()` is always an integer value representing a number of pixels.

Note that **`.style.width` only applies to inline styles**.

- HTML:

  ```
  <div id="mydivInlineStyle" style="width: 10cm"><b>Inline style:</b>
  </div>

  <div id="mydivExternalStylesheet"><b>External stylesheet:</b> 
  </div>
  ```
- CSS:

  ```
  div { 
    width: 10cm; 
    border: 10px solid blue; padding: 11px; margin: 12px; 
    background: aqua; white-space: pre; 
  }
  ```
- JS:

  ```
  $('div').each(function(){ 
    $(this).append(
      'jQuery width(): ' + $(this).width() + "\n" + 
      '.css(\'width\'): ' + $(this).css('width') + "\n" + 
      '.style.width: ' + this.style.width
    ); 
  });
  ```
- Output:

  ```
  Inline style: 
    jQuery width(): 378 
    .css('width'): 378px 
    .style.width: 10cm

  External stylesheet: 
    jQuery width(): 378 
    .css('width'): 378px 
    .style.width:
  ```

Answer (score 0):

`.width()` will give you what is applied
`.css('width')` will give you what is in the style attribute

Comment: Any idea why .css('width') and .style.width would be different? The cells have borders, if that's relevant. The first is returning '123px' and the second gives me '124px', which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

`.css('width')` returns the attribute with the unit appended while `.width()` does not, it will give you the number in pixels.

So if you have an element with a width of 200px `.css('width')` will return "200px" while `.width()` will return 200.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a difference in "intended width" vs. real width. `.width()` will give you the content width of an element, `.css("width")` will give you the width as intended by the style sheet.